# $AB = C$, prove if $C$ is invertible, then $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A, B, C$ be $n \times n$ matrices and assume $AB = C$. Prove if $C$ is invertible, then $A$ and $B$ are invertible and specify inverses.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729990/prove-that-if-a-and-b-are-square-matrices-and-ab-is-invertible-then-both?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Let $D$ be the inverse of $C$. Then $CD=DC=I$. Now multiply $AB=C$ by $D$ separately on the right and on the left.

If you don't need to give the inverses, just compute the determinant on both sides.

Comment: Is this true in the infinite-dimensional case? (I mean, the fact that $A$ and $B$ are invertible if their product is)

Comment: @Giuseppe It appears that this proof works for functions in general whose composition is invertible, I would expect it to apply to the infinite dimensional case

Comment: @pjs36 this is definitely wrong in the infinite dimensional case. The argument only shows that $A$ has a right inverse (which corresponds to "surjective") and $B$ has a left inverse (which corresponds to "injective"). But only in the finite dimensional case this is enough to conclude that $A$ and $B$ are invertible.